# Touchpad or Trackpad Issue on Fujitsu T934 Laptop: Works in Ubuntu 22.04 Only After Restarting from Windows 10, Stops Working After Sleep Mode

Tags: touchpad

The trackpad of my laptop Fujitsu T934 works in Ubuntu 22.04 only when I restart it from Windows 10 and even stop working after once it goes to sleep mode. If I boot Ubuntu directly after the shutdown the trackpad does not work either.